# Plotting a lines chart for data that is already pivoted with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

For this data that is **already pivoted** in a dataframe:

```
             1     2     3     4     5     6     7
2013-05-28  -0.44  0.03  0.06 -0.31  0.13  0.56  0.81
2013-07-05   0.84  1.03  0.96  0.90  1.09  0.59  1.15
2013-08-21   0.09  0.25  0.06  0.09 -0.09 -0.16  0.56
2014-10-15   0.35  1.16  1.91  3.44  2.75  1.97  2.16
2015-02-09   0.09 -0.10 -0.38 -0.69 -0.25 -0.85 -0.47
```

.. I'm trying to make a lines chart. This from Excel:

[image: chart]

.. and if I click that flip x & y button in Excel, also this pic:

[image: another chart]

I'm getting lost with the to-chart and to-png steps, and most of the examples want unpivoted raw data, which is something I'm passed.

Seaborn or Matplotlib or anything that can make the chart would be great. On a box without X11 would be better still :)

I thought about posting this a comment on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29933536/832725), but I could not do newlines, insert pics and all of that.

Edit: Sorry, I've not pasted in any of the attempts I've tried because they have not even come close to putting a PNG out. The only other examples on SO I can see start with transactional rows, and pivot for sure, but don't go as far as PNG output.

Comment: What code have you attempted so far?

Comment: You're getting lost but have you done any research on this or made any attempt at all? This might be helpful- https://matplotlib.org/users/beginner.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to transpose your data before plotting it.

```
df.T.plot()
```